# Entity Framework code-first : how do I add an entity that is related to an existing entity?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

There is a `Products` table. Each product has a list of reviews. When products are added, initially they don't have reviews. I am trying to add a review to an existing product by adding to the `List<Review>` inside the product but it's throwing an error

> Multiplicity constraint violated

Product.cs

```
namespace DatabaseProject.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public Product()
        {
            Reviews = new List < Review >();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Catagory Catagory { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Specification { get; set; }
        public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Review.cs

```
namespace DatabaseProject.Models
{
    public class Review
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int Stars { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Method to add a new product

```
public Product Add(Product product)
{
    using (var context = new ShopDbContext())
    {
        context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;
        var response = context.Products.Add(product);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return response;
    }
}
```

Method to add a new review

```
public bool AddReview(int id, Review review)
{
    using (var context = new ShopDbContext())
    {
        Product oldProduct = context.Products.Find(id);

        if (oldProduct == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        oldProduct.Reviews.Add(review);

        context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Adding a new product. This works fine.

```
Product p = new Product
{
    Catagory = Catagory.COMPUTER,
    Name = "Surface Pro 3",
    Description = "Tablet / Laptop",
    Specification = "i5 16 GB ram",
};


productService.Add(p);
```

Adding a new review:

```
Review review = new Review
{
    Customer = customerService.Get(1),
    Product = productService.Get(1),
    Stars = 2,
    Text = "It's a good camera",
};

productService.AddReview(1, review);
```

Throws this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Review_Product_Target' of the relationship 'DatabaseProject.Review_Product' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.'

EDIT

Sorry I forgot to mention this.

I also have a `Customer` table which stores a set of reviews made by that customer. Is this somehow causing the error?

```
namespace DatabaseProject.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {
            Addresses = new List<Address>();
            Reviews = new List<Review>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Without testing, I'd say that the issue is that you have already set the `Product` property of the `Review` object and that has already set up the relationship, so adding it to a `Reviews` collection is superfluous.  I would think that you should be doing one or the other but not both.

Comment: @jmcilhinney if I remove the product property in the Review object, I won't be able to retrieve the product associated with that review. For example I have a Customer table that is also linked to Review. So if I retrieve reviews made by a particular customer, I should be able to retrieve the associated product for each review.

Comment: I didn't say that you should remove that property from that type.

Comment: @jmcilhinney that solved it! When I didn't enter Product in the Review object. If you could give it as an answer I can select as correct answer. Thank you!!